# Applet shows empty in the browser

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, applet

This applet is suppose to show two pictures in top of each other. When i run this applet in the browser it doesn't show the pictures. The pictures names are correct and they are located in the same folder as the applet.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JApplet;


public class question3b extends JApplet{


    public void init() {
        repaint();
        }

     public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon("1.JPG");
        ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon("2.JPG");
        g.drawImage(image1.getImage(), 100, 20 , 100, 100, this);
        g.drawImage(image2.getImage(), 100, 150 , 100, 100, this);

  }
}
```

This is the HTML page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome Java Applet</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet
  code = "question3b.class"
  width = 1000
  height = 500>
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is to do with how you are loading your images

```
ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon("2.JPG");
```

Assumes that the image source is a local file on the clients hard disk, which is potentially, amongst other things, an illegal operation.

The answer will depend on where the file is stored.  If the image is an embedded resource within your applications jar, the you should be using

```
ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/2.JPG"));
```

If the image is stored in the web server, then you should be using

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), "2.jpg");
    img = ImageIO.read(url);
} catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And inset everything that Hovercraft has just said (+1)

Comment: it worked perfectly because i'm using wamp to test my page but i didn't use the try and catch code that u gave me, btw the previous code it shows just fine when i test it with netbeans.

Comment: The applet viewer doesn't have the same restrictions as the browser, so it can see the file system. ImageIO is more robust (and supports more image formats), because it throws an Exception, it means its easier to diagnose

Answer (score 4):

### Recommendations:

- Don't override a JApplet's paint method.
- Instead override a JPanel's paintComponent method and display the panel in the applet.
- Don't call repaint() in the paintComponent method. Please.
- Don't read in images in the paint or paintComponent method. Read the image in *once* only.
- Don't read the image in as a file but rather as a resource.
- Test to make sure that you're looking in the right location for the image.
- You would benefit much by reading a few tutorials on Swing graphics as much of what you're doing looks like you're doing a bit of guessing. The tutorials will show you the right way to do things. You won't regret reading them.
- Even better than painting the images in a JPanel is to put them into ImageIcons and display them in JLabels.

Comment: and how can i override a JPanel's paintComponent method, i'll try to search for the tutorials

Comment: @BasilBasaif: you're reading the image each time `paint(...)` is called. Not only is that unnecessary, but it will slow down your GUI's graphics to a crawl. paint and paintComponent need to be lean, mean, and **fast** and involved with painting *only*.

Comment: @BasilBasaif Have a read through [Performng custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: Add use ImageIO instead of ImageIcon (please ;))